# apt-getをmacOSで使えるようにするには

Tags: linux, macos, apt

`sudo apt-get update`はmacosでlinuxをインストールすれば使えるのでしょうか？

調べたら本来macosには対応していないという回答が多かったので気になって質問しました。
brewやmacportsで実行するも "command not found" になってしまいます。
ちなみにapt-getの代わりになりmacで使えるようなものは何がありますかね？
初学者なもので質問文はご了承お願いします。

Answer (score 1):

`apt (apt-get)` は Linux の中でも主に Debian/Ubuntu 系のディストリビューションで使用される **パッケージ管理のコマンド** です。Linux には色々な種類があり、他にもメジャーなパッケージ管理のコマンドとして `yum (dnf)` などがありますが、**OS の種類が違えばコマンドも違ってきます**。

macOS も広義の意味では Linux ベースと言えるのかもしれませんが、パッケージ管理の仕組みは違うので `apt` コマンドは使えません。

---

少し調べると macOS 上でも apt の動作を真似して動かす方法は一応あるようですが、手間もかかるしメリットは薄いと思います。素直に Homebrew や Macports を使って管理したほうが良さそうです。

参考:
[How to install apt-get or YUM on Mac OS X](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80711)

Comment: [macOSは BSD系](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux#/media/File:Unix_timeline.en.svg) もしくは(広義では) UNIX系で, Linuxとは別系統です(Linuxも UNIXの括りだけど)